# Pandas Replace NaN in column A from column B

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe as shown below:

```
     A     B     C
0    a1    b1    c1
1    a2    b1    c2
2    NaN   b2    c3
3    NaN   b2    c4
4    NaN   b3    c5
5    NaN   b3    c6
6    NaN   b3    c7
7    a3    b4    c8
8    a4    b4    c9
```

I would like to remove NaN values from column A and replace them with column B values that it looks like below:

```
     A     B     C
0    a1    b1    c1
1    a2    b1    c2
2    b2    b2    c3
3    b2    b2    c4
4    b3    b3    c5
5    b3    b3    c6
6    b3    b3    c7
7    a3    b4    c8
8    a4    b4    c9
```

Comment: `df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'])`

Comment: replace will also work:   df['A'] = df['A']..replace(np.nan, df['B'])